# js list of strings to string

Tags: javascript, typescript

I need to convert list of strings

```
const ar: string[] = ['str1', 'str2']
```

to a string which contains `ar` container with square brackets `[]` and quotes `"`

```
const str: string = `["str1", "str2"]`
```

how to do it in proper way?

Comment: `JSON.stringify(ar)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format you want is a JSON array string. So use the JSON object's stringify function.
`JSON.stringify(["some", "array", 123]);`